# Is browser share data available through the data explorer or otherwise for 2012?

Tags: discussion

Does Stack exchange provide any sort of browser share and screen size data systematically other than the occasional blog post ([like this one from August, 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/)). I'm wondering if moderators have any access to their site data as well as if anyone has publicly available access to such data through the data explorer at http://data.stackexchange.com or elsewhere.

Comment: Moderators currently don't have access to this data.

Comment: Does Quantcast have this data, perhaps?

Comment: @Aarthi Ooh - it looks like there is at least a mobile / desktop breakdown of stats publicly available for many of the sites: https://www.quantcast.com/apple.stackexchange.com#!mobileWeb and https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#!mobileWeb